# How to get a "warning window" to come up before moving files by clicking and dragging?

Tags: windows-xp

Fairly regularly I left double-click to open a folder, as usual, but instead manage to move the entire folder into another one (the folder above it or below it) by accident.

Any tips on getting a "warning window" to come up before a move occurs? That way I can just hit cancel (unless of course I hit OK by accident too :)

Comment: you could turn the drag/drop off as a workaround , if you need that just leave a comment here

Comment: The drag and drop is great; it's just that I wish I had a confirmation window appear before the actual move. That would save me the extra hassle of unmoving accidentally moved files...you get the idea.

Comment: Maybe you could adjust your mouse settings? I'm thinking adjusting the double-click timer may help? Unlikely, but thought I'd mention it in case you've not explored those options yet.

Comment: @Andraz I have been searching for the answer or any tool to do so in Google search from the time you posted this question . I am not able to find it any-where.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do what you want; not built into Explorer anyway.  The suggestion of increasing drag threshold will probably help though.  Another thing that helps me in this situation is **undo**.  If you accidentally do something in Explorer (including the desktop and most other folders), as long as you notice that something unintended happened, you can go to Explorer's menu and select Edit > Undo.  A summary of what will be undone is displayed in the status bar at the bottom of the Explorer window if you navigate to Undo without actually clicking it or pressing Enter.

Comment: @subanki and boot13--thanks for your help and suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should increase the *drag threshold* of your mouse. This is a value that determines how far you must click-and-drag before Windows will recognize the action as a "move" operation. [This article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/2009/04/10) explains what you're trying to achieve.

You can use [Windows XP Power Toys](https://web.archive.org/web/20160326154927/http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx) to change the mouse sensitivity ([direct download link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150511160114/http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/c/a/fca6767b-9ed9-45a6-b352-839afb2a2679/TweakUIPowertoySetup_ia64.exe)). Select Mouse and change the "Drag" on right side. You might want to set the drag threshold to a very large value like 50 or 100 pixels, or a smaller value if that is enough to prevent the mistakes you're seeing.

Alternative: [This page](https://www.parkscomputing.com/2009/04/windows-drag-sensitivity-utility/) contains a tool that will help you set your mouse sensitivity. Here is a [direct download link](https://web.archive.org/web/20130602032727/http://www.parkscomputing.com/dragsens.zip) to the tool.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant answer. Works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This is an ancient question but it has high Google pagerank so in the hopes of helping other searchers I thought I would add an answer that works very well for me now with Windows 10:

http://broken-e.com/dragdropconfirm/

It is on github as well. If the website above is not working, you can get it here: https://github.com/broken-e/DragDropConfirm/tree/master/Installer